# BOTH Broadcom controllers disabled

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom, ethernet

I have Trusty Tahr (Ubuntu 14.04) and the usual advice on proprietary drivers is not working. In 'Additional Drivers' it says about the Broadcom drivers "This device is not working". So I do some lspci -nn and find I have Wireless 14e4:4311 (rev 01) and Ethernet 14e4:170c (rev 02). I have googled what to do about reinstalling either of these, but all the answers require 'apt-get update', but I can not run any of these lines if both drivers are not operational.

Thanks for any pointers,
array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: While I agree with the duplicate, the process to rescue himself is rather complex. I will shortcut the process and answer the question before it get closed as a duplicate!

Answer (score 2):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot. Your ethernet should now be working. Next, do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot once again and all should be working.